# Bluehost MySQL and phpmyadmin select sql service.php running slow while insert, delete, and update commands works instantly

Tags: php

I am using crud commands in an app and my commands for insert, delete and update in sql work instantly. The select query in my php file called service loads in a few hours. I was wondering what was causing this. It doesn't really make since to me considering the other commands work instantly. Besides it not loading in my app I have it in a website where I can view my table with the php file. This does not load either...

I have my service on a website secured with HTTPS, is there anything on bluehost that I need to change in settings? I also posted my code below for my php file. I've tried a few other coded formats and commented these out of which none work anyway. This leads me to believe this is some setting in bluehost. Anyone else with the same problems and found a solution they could share or any ideas of why this is happening?

```
<?php
   
$start = microtime(TRUE);
error_log('Connecting');
// Create connection
$connection=mysqli_connect("localhost","mlbroadv_admin","DpApp&483",
"mlbroadv_PlantAssistDB");
 
// Check connection
if ($connection == false) {
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. "
                .mysqli_connect_error());
}
 
// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'


error_log('Connection took' . microtime(TRUE) - $start);
// Check connection
// if ($connection == false) {
//     die("ERROR: Could not connect. " .mysqli_connect_error());
// }
// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
//$sql = "SELECT * FROM Notes";
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Notes";

error_log('Running select');
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql)){
    error_log('Select took' . microtime(TRUE) - $start);
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    // Loop through each row in the result set
    error_log('looping fetch');
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        error_log('Fetch is running at ' . microtime(TRUE) - $start);
        // Add each row into our results array
        $resultArray[] = $row;
    }
    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
error_log('Fetch is done at ' . microtime(TRUE) - $start);
// Close connections
mysqli_close($connection);
error_log('Connection closed at ' . microtime(TRUE) - $start);
?>
```

EDIT

Results for time

```
[27-Jul-2022 07:17:15 America/Boise] Connecting
[27-Jul-2022 07:17:15 America/Boise] Connection took0.010892868041992
[27-Jul-2022 07:17:15 America/Boise] Running select
[27-Jul-2022 07:17:15 America/Boise] Select took0.012121915817261
[27-Jul-2022 07:17:15 America/Boise] looping fetch
[27-Jul-2022 07:17:15 America/Boise] Fetch is running at 0.012276887893677
[27-Jul-2022 07:17:15 America/Boise] Fetch is running at 0.012364864349365
[27-Jul-2022 07:17:15 America/Boise] Fetch is running at 0.012436866760254
[27-Jul-2022 07:17:15 America/Boise] Fetch is running at 0.012504816055298
[27-Jul-2022 07:17:15 America/Boise] Fetch is done at 0.012606859207153
[27-Jul-2022 07:17:15 America/Boise] Connection closed at 0.012848854064941
```

Comment: Does the query execute slowly when accessing DB directly? How many rows are you trying to fetch? Unrelated but `$tempArray = $row; array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);` is the same as `$resultArray[] = $row;`, easier to read/write IMO.

Comment: This is only 4 rows by 3 columns. it is a test database. No in phpmyadmin it responds instantly. Only when accessing through php it runs slow.

Comment: Output `time()` prior to `mysqli_query(`, after that, and inside the loop. Where is time being spent?

Comment: I'm trying to view it atm my editor dosn't let me view outputs

Comment: Could use https://3v4l.org/5Jr3N to write outputs to your server logs.

Comment: Thanks, is giving output now

Comment: Where does the execution time hang, `fetch`?

Comment: Got busy today, I wasnt able to get it to connect. I'm not sure how to connect outside of the localhost. I tried using the bluehost ip address with it in different ways and my website address too.

Comment: If you can't connect than DML ( insert, delete and update) can't work either, right?

Comment: I was able to find where the log was reporting and posted my results as an edit to the question

Comment: This shows the script took `0.012` seconds to run. Each fetch takes `0.001` second to run.

Comment: Interesting...I wonder why the website doesn't update instantly too when phpmyadmin updates instantly.

Comment: This question is getting less clear.. there are no updates being done here, just a `select`, that select also is taking < 1 second to run, not hours. Is the issue out of date data, or page loads taking hours for the `select` statement?

Comment: After some research too and narrowing down that it's not the php. I think it's the DNS server loading the page slowly. I'm calling bluehost to see if I can change the DNS server ip. Otherwise, it must be a setting on bluehost somewhere.

Comment: Can run a traceroute to see where the connection hangs... or possibly curl with verbose.. leaving my area of expertise here though. Good luck